# Android add imageview programmatically fix size all screen

Tags: java, android

I'm creating several ImageViews programmatically, but I'm running into an issue where there are different ImageView sizes on different displays.
I want the ImageView size to be fixed on all screens. Here is how I am generating those ImageViews:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myImageList.size(); i++) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(myImageList.get(i));
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(420, 210);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    float angleDeg = i * 360.0f / myImageList.size() - 70.0f;
    float angleRad = (float) (angleDeg * Math.PI / 180.0f);
    iv.setTranslationX(320 * (float) Math.cos(angleRad));
    iv.setTranslationY(320 * (float) Math.sin(angleRad));
    iv.setRotation(angleDeg + 80.0f);
    main.addView(iv);
    final int finalI = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce new class derived from ImageView and make all those adjustments in that class. Then just replaces ImageView to your class implementation in layouts etc

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple interpretations of your questions.

1. The `ImageView` should have same size on all the devices - use `dp`. You are using `pixels` right now in the `LayoutParams`.
2. The `ImageView` should look that it has same size on all screens - find the width and height of the screen, set an aspect ration, eg. 0.33 and use that factored width and height in `LayoutParams`.
3. Use `MATCH_PARENT` in LayoutParams for width as well as height and the ImageView will take the full size (of the parent).

This question has a lot of great explanation about `dp`, `px`, `sp` that could be useful - [What is the difference between "px", "dip", "dp" and "sp"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)

Answer (score 0):

To find screen sizes

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    // these are sizes in pixels
    metrics.widthPixels, metric.heightPixels
```

Then, you can use this

```
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

See this link for all ScaleType values

[Android ImageView ScaleType: A Visual Guide](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide)